# Adding model to Backbone.localstorage Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-local-storage

I am trying to add a model to a collection which will be stored in local storage via the Backbone.localstorage plugin.

The code for adding the model in the collection is as follows:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'model/articleModel', 'backbone', 'localstorage' ],     function($, _, itsModel, Backbone) {
    var articleCache = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: itsModel,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("articles-backbone-cache"),

        addArticle: function(model){
            console.log('Adding new article ID [' + model.id + '] Title [' + model.title     + '] to cache via backbone.localstorage');
            console.log(model);

            //CRUCIAL PART
            this.create(model); // Doesn't work
            this.create(model.toJSON()); //Doesn't work
            this.create({id: model.id}); // Works but only id is saved and naturally all other attributes are set to defaults
        }
    });

    return articleCache;
});
```

The model is:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'localstorage' ], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var article = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            id : '0',
            title : '',
            subtitile : '',
            date : '',
            section : '',
            section_id : -1,
            subsection : null,
            subsection_id : null,
            noOfComments : 0
    });

    return article;
});
```

The problem is that the model is not being saved to local storage. It only saves to local storage when I use "this.create({id: model.id});" but missing all other attributes.

The model being passed to addArticle(model) is the same as the one it's expecting, can anyone give some help on how to persist this data to local storage ?

I would hate to write the following since it is already in that form:

```
this.create({id: model.id, title:model.title, . . . })
```

Comment: make sure all your models have id and different ids.

Comment: Check and check. The model I am trying to save to this collection is retrieved from a remote server using normal Backbone REST calls. So all ids are unique and non-null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use `add` instead of `create`

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create `collection.create(attributes, [options])`

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add `collection.add(models, [options])`

Comment: I have tried using add, that also doesn't work. Also, according to [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html) the create method is supposed to be used in the case of the local storage plugin. EDIT: Using add() fails in all 3 cases I outlined in the original question.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to play with.

Answer (score 0):

To add the model to the collection, you should be using the `add` function.

This adds the model to the collection, but the sync doesn't happen to the localStorage yet.

To persist the added model to the localStorage, you have to call `model.save()`.

HTH!